# Search Edittext in Sherlock Acionbar

Tags: android, android-edittext, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem with search view in sherlock actionbar so i decided to use edit text instead. but when I want to use edit text my app crash (android 2.3). how could I use search edittext or searchview in sherlock activity for android 2.3?

here is my onCreateOptionsMenu function:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater minflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    minflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

and this is my edittext xml source:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txt_search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/black"     
    />
```

and my search menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" 
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="@layout/search_layout"
    />
```

If anyone knows a way to use searchview in sherlock activity or use edittext for search in sherlock actionbar, notice me.

Comment: I didn't use sherlock activity but i've used Textwatcher for filtering my lists with EditText (sort of searching!)hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Answer (score 0):

work for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

// "0" is the number of menu item search in my example 
menu.getItem(0).setActionView(R.layout.your_layout_search); //your layout with edittext
EditText editSearch = (EditText) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.edit_search);

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```